# Duplicate rule names

Tags: drools, kie-workbench

I am using kie-workbench. When a rule is created from **Guided Decision Table** or **Guided Rule Tamplet**. It throws the error "Duplicate declaration for variable". But if same rule is created using DRL file it works fine.

Rules.drl

```
package in.drooltest.test2;
import in.drooltest.coupon.model.Order;

rule "rulesdrl22_0"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        ooorrr : Order( customerId == 1 )
    then
        ooorrr.setAmount( 232323232 );
end
```

calling it in java project.

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
ReleaseId releaseId = kieServices.newReleaseId("in.drooltest", "test2", "1.0");
KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(releaseId);
KieScanner kScanner = kieServices.newKieScanner(kieContainer);
kScanner.start( 10000L );


KieSession kSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
Order order = new Order();
order.setCustomerId(100000000);
kSession.insert(order);

kSession.fireAllRules();
kSession.dispose();
```

This rule was generated from Guided Decision Templet. It throws run time error.. **Unable to build KieBaseModel:defaultKieBase [4,0]: Duplicate rule name: rulesdrl22_0 Duplicate declaration for variable 'ooorrr'**

But after deleting the template and pasting it in rules.drl file it worked as expected.

Tried deleting jar file and regenerate it, but didn't help.

Comment: What is it: duplicate *rule* name or duplicate *declaration*? Show the rule text producing the error.